# PHP код выдает ошибку Notice: Undefined variable:

Tags: php

[19-Sep-2018 16:54:52 UTC] PHP Notice:  Undefined variable: message in

```
$method = $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'];

$c = true;
$message;
if ( $method === 'POST' ) {

    $project_name = trim($_POST["project_name"]);
    $admin_email  = trim($_POST["admin_email"]);
    $form_subject = trim($_POST["form_subject"]);


    foreach ( $_POST as $key => $value ) {
        if ( $value != "" && $key != "project_name" && $key != "admin_email" && $key != "form_subject" ) {
            $value = strip_tags( $value );
            $message .= "
            " . ( ($c = !$c) ? '<tr>':'<tr style="background-color: #f8f8f8;">' ) . "
                <td style='padding: 10px; border: #e9e9e9 1px solid;'><b>$key</b></td>
                <td style='padding: 10px; border: #e9e9e9 1px solid;'>$value</td>
            </tr>
            "; <- выбивает ошибку вот здесь
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$method = $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'];

$c = true;
$message = '';
if ( $method === 'POST' ) {

    $project_name = trim($_POST["project_name"]);
    $admin_email  = trim($_POST["admin_email"]);
    $form_subject = trim($_POST["form_subject"]);


    foreach ( $_POST as $key => $value ) {
        if ( $value != "" && $key != "project_name" && $key != "admin_email" && $key != "form_subject" ) {
            $value = strip_tags( $value );
            $message .= "
            " . ( ($c = !$c) ? '<tr>':'<tr style="background-color: #f8f8f8;">' ) . "
                <td style='padding: 10px; border: #e9e9e9 1px solid;'><b>$key</b></td>
                <td style='padding: 10px; border: #e9e9e9 1px solid;'>$value</td>
            </tr>
            "; <- Теперь тут не будет этого предупреждения, даже не предупреждения, а уведомления =)
        }
    }
}
```