# Notice: Undefined variable

Tags: php

Ошибки
Undefined variable: dt  on line 212
Notice: Undefined variable: add 
как поправить?

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="ru">
<head>
<title>Список всех партнеров и наличие их в базе сайта</title>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
    <link href="js/jquery.jgrowl.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-rwoIResjU2yc3z8GV/NPeZWAv56rSmLldC3R/AZzGRnGxQQKnKkoFVhFQhNUwEyJ" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.jgrowl.js"></script>
    <script src="jquery.maskedinput.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="script.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/v/bs4/dt-1.10.20/datatables.min.css"/>

 <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/v/bs4/dt-1.10.20/datatables.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <?php
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_startup_errors', 1);
ini_set('display_errors', '1');
    $host = 'localhost';  // Хост, у нас все локально
    $user = 'root';    // Имя созданного вами пользователя
    $pass = ''; // Установленный вами пароль пользователю
    $db_name = 'test100';   // Имя базы данных
    $link = mysqli_connect($host, $user, $pass, $db_name); // Соединяемся с базой
    // Ругаемся, если соединение установить не удалось

    // Ругаемся, если соединение установить не удалось
    if (!$link) {
      echo 'Не могу соединиться с БД. Код ошибки: ' . mysqli_connect_errno() . ', ошибка: ' . mysqli_connect_error();
      exit;
    }

    //Если переменная name передана
    if (isset($_POST["name"])) {
      //Если это запрос на обновление, то обновляем
      if (isset($_GET['red_id'])) {
          $sql = mysqli_query($link, "UPDATE `users` SET `name` = '{$_POST['name']}',`category` = '{$_POST['category']}',`region` = '{$_POST['region']}',`money` = '{$_POST['money']}',`area` = '{$_POST['area']}',`etaj` = '{$_POST['etaj']}',`tip-doma` = '{$_POST['tip-doma']}',`phone` = '{$_POST['phone']}',`premich` = '{$_POST['premich']}',`time` = '{$_POST['time']}' WHERE `id`={$_GET['red_id']}");
      } else {
          //Иначе вставляем данные, подставляя их в запрос
          $sql = mysqli_query($link, "INSERT INTO `users` (`name`, `category`, `region`, `money`, `area`, `etaj`, `tip-doma`, `phone`, `premich`, `time`) VALUES ('{$_POST['name']}', '{$_POST['category']}', '{$_POST['region']}', '{$_POST['money']}', '{$_POST['area']}', '{$_POST['etaj']}', '{$_POST['tip-doma']}', '{$_POST['phone']}', '{$_POST['premich']}', '{$_POST['time']}')");
      }

      //Если вставка прошла успешно
      if ($sql) {
        echo '<script type="text/javascript"> ';
        echo '$.jGrowl("Успешно!", { 
            theme: "green"});';
      } else {
        echo '$.jGrowl("Произошла ошибка: ' . mysqli_error($link) . '", { 
            theme: "red"
        });';
      }
      echo '</script>';
    }

    if (isset($_GET['del_id'])) { //проверяем, есть ли переменная
      //удаляем строку из таблицы
      $sql = mysqli_query($link, "DELETE FROM `users` WHERE `id` = {$_GET['del_id']}");
      if ($sql) {
        echo '<script type="text/javascript"> ';
        echo '$.jGrowl("Пользователь удален!", { 
            theme: "green"});';
      } else {
        echo '$.jGrowl("Произошла ошибка: ' . mysqli_error($link) . '", { 
            theme: "red"
        });';
      }
      echo '</script>';
    }

    //Если передана переменная red_id, то надо обновлять данные. Для начала достанем их из БД
    if (isset($_GET['red_id'])) {
      $sql = mysqli_query($link, "SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE `id`={$_GET['red_id']}");
      $product = mysqli_fetch_array($sql);
    }
    if (isset($_GET['red_id'])) {
        $edit = 'Изменение клиента';
        $date= $product['time'];
        }else {
            $add = 'Добавление клиента в базу';
            $dt=date('d-m-Y');
          }

  ?> 

  <form action="" method="post">
  <div class="resultat">
  <div class="box-header">
    <div class="title"><?= $add ?><?= $edit ?> <?= isset($_GET['red_id']) ? $product['name'] : ''; ?></div>
  </div>
  <div class="box-content">
    <table>
      <tr>
        <td>Имя:</td>
        <td><input type="text" name="name" value="<?= isset($_GET['red_id']) ? $product['name'] : ''; ?>"></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Телефон:</td>
        <td><input required id="phone1" type="text" name="phone" value="<?= isset($_GET['red_id']) ? $product['phone'] : ''; ?>"></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Категория:</td>
        <td>
        <select name="category" x-autocompletetype="name">
        <option value=""></option>
        <optgroup label="Квартиры">
    <option value="Однокомнатная квартира" <?= $product['category']=='Однокомнатная квартира' ? ' selected' : ''; ?>>Однокомнатная квартира</option>
    <option value="Двухкомнатная квартира" <?= $product['category']=='Двухкомнатная квартира' ? ' selected' : ''; ?>>Двухкомнатная квартира</option>
    <option value="Трёхкомнатная квартира" <?= $product['category']=='Трёхкомнатная квартира' ? ' selected' : ''; ?>>Трёхкомнатная квартира</option>
    <option value="Четырёхкомнатная квартира" <?= $product['category']=='Четырёхкомнатная квартира' ? ' selected' : ''; ?>>Четырёхкомнатная квартира</option>
    <option value="Более четырёх комнат" <?= $product['category']=='Более четырёх комнат' ? ' selected' : ''; ?>>Более четырёх комнат</option>
    <option value="Все квартиры" <?= $product['category']=='Все квартиры' ? ' selected' : ''; ?>>Все квартиры</option>
    </optgroup>
    <optgroup label="Дома">
    <option value="Дом в деревне" <?= $product['category']=='Дом в деревне' ? ' selected' : ''; ?>>в деревне</option>
    <option value="Дом в городе" <?= $product['category']=='Дом в городе' ? ' selected' : ''; ?>>в городе</option>
    <option value="Все дома" <?= $product['category']=='Все дома' ? ' selected' : ''; ?>>Все дома</option>
    </optgroup>
    <optgroup label="Земельные участки">
    <option value="Земельный участок в городе" <?= $product['category']=='Земельный участок в городе' ? ' selected' : ''; ?>>В городе</option>
    <option value="Земельные участок в деревне" <?= $product['category']=='Земельные участок в деревне' ? ' selected' : ''; ?>>В деревне</option>
    <option value="Земельные участок в снт" <?= $product['category']=='Земельные участок в снт' ? ' selected' : ''; ?>>В снт</option>
    <option value="Все земельные участки" <?= $product['category']=='Все земельные участки' ? ' selected' : ''; ?>>Все земельные участки</option>
    </optgroup>
    <optgroup label="Другие районы">
    <option value="Санкт петербург" <?= $product['category']=='Санкт петербург' ? ' selected' : ''; ?>>Санкт петербург</option>
    <option value="Владимир" <?= $product['category']=='Владимир' ? ' selected' : ''; ?>>Владимир</option>
    <option value="Абхазия" <?= $product['category']=='Абхазия' ? ' selected' : ''; ?>>Абхазия</option>
    <option value="Москва" <?= $product['category']=='Москва' ? ' selected' : ''; ?>>Москва</option>
    <option value="Московская область" <?= $product['category']=='Московская область' ? ' selected' : ''; ?>>Московская область</option>
    <option value="Дачный поселок" <?= $product['category']=='Дачный поселок' ? ' selected' : ''; ?>>дачный поселок</option>
    <option value="Другой район" <?= $product['category']=='другие районы' ? ' selected' : ''; ?>>другие районы</option>
    </optgroup>
    <optgroup label="Прочее">
    <option value="Комната" <?= $product['category']=='Комната' ? ' selected' : ''; ?>>Комната</option>
    <option value="Новостройка" <?= $product['category']=='Новостройка' ? ' selected' : ''; ?>>Новостройка</option>
    <option value="Аренда квартир" <?= $product['category']=='Аренда квартир' ? ' selected' : ''; ?>>Аренда квартир</option>
    <option value="Коммерческая недвижимость" <?= $product['category']=='Коммерческая недвижимость' ? ' selected' : ''; ?>>Коммерческая недвижимость</option>
    <option value="СНТ" <?= $product['category']=='СНТ' ? ' selected' : ''; ?>>СНТ</option>
    <option value="Гараж" <?= $product['category']=='Гараж' ? ' selected' : ''; ?>>Гараж</option>
    <option value="Обмен" <?= $product['category']=='Обмен' ? ' selected' : ''; ?>>Обмен</option>
    </optgroup>
                </select>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Район:</td>
        <td>
        <select name="region" x-autocompletetype="name">
        <option value=""></option>
    <option value="Центр" <?= $product['region']=='Центр' ? ' selected' : ''; ?>>Центр</option>
    <option value="Аэродром" <?= $product['region']=='Аэродром' ? ' selected' : ''; ?>>Аэродром</option>
    <option value="Ленинский" <?= $product['region']=='Ленинский' ? ' selected' : ''; ?>>Ленинский</option>
    <option value="Сахалин" <?= $product['region']=='Сахалин' ? ' selected' : ''; ?>>Сахалин</option>
    <option value="Белая речка" <?= $product['region']=='Белая речка' ? ' selected' : ''; ?>>Белая речка</option>
                </select>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Бюджет:</td>
        <td><input type="text" name="money" value="<?= isset($_GET['red_id']) ? $product['money'] : ''; ?>"></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Площадь:</td>
        <td><input type="text" name="area" value="<?= isset($_GET['red_id']) ? $product['area'] : ''; ?>"></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Этаж:</td>
        <td>
        <select name="etaj" x-autocompletetype="name">
        <option value=""></option>
    <option value="1 этаж" <?= $product['etaj']=='1этаж' ? ' selected' : ''; ?>>1 этаж</option>
    <option value="2 этаж" <?= $product['etaj']=='2 этаж' ? ' selected' : ''; ?>>2 этаж</option>
    <option value="3 этаж" <?= $product['etaj']=='3 этаж' ? ' selected' : ''; ?>>3 этаж</option>
    <option value="4 этаж" <?= $product['etaj']=='4 этаж' ? ' selected' : ''; ?>>4 этаж</option>
    <option value="5 этаж" <?= $product['etaj']=='5 этаж' ? ' selected' : ''; ?>>5 этаж</option>
    <option value="6 этаж" <?= $product['etaj']=='6 этаж' ? ' selected' : ''; ?>>6 этаж</option>
    <option value="7 этаж" <?= $product['etaj']=='7 этаж' ? ' selected' : ''; ?>>7 этаж</option>
    <option value="8 этаж" <?= $product['etaj']=='8 этаж' ? ' selected' : ''; ?>>8 этаж</option>
    <option value="9 этаж" <?= $product['etaj']=='9 этаж' ? ' selected' : ''; ?>>9 этаж</option>
    <option value="10 этаж" <?= $product['etaj']=='10 этаж' ? ' selected' : ''; ?>>10 этаж</option>
                </select>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Тип дома:</td>
        <td>
        <select name="tip-doma" x-autocompletetype="tip-doma">
        <option value=""></option>
    <option value="Монолитный" <?= $product['tip-doma']=='Монолитный' ? ' selected' : ''; ?>>Монолитный</option>
    <option value="Кирпичный" <?= $product['tip-doma']=='Кирпичный' ? ' selected' : ''; ?>>Кирпичный</option>
    <option value="Панельный" <?= $product['tip-doma']=='Панельный' ? ' selected' : ''; ?>>Панельный</option>
    <option value="Деревянный" <?= $product['tip-doma']=='Деревянный' ? ' selected' : ''; ?>>Деревянный</option>
    <option value="Брус" <?= $product['tip-doma']=='Брус' ? ' selected' : ''; ?>>Брус</option>
    <option value="Бревенчатый" <?= $product['tip-doma']=='Бревенчатый' ? ' selected' : ''; ?>>Бревенчатый</option>
    <option value="Оцилиндрованный" <?= $product['tip-doma']=='Оцилиндрованный' ? ' selected' : ''; ?>>Оцилиндрованный</option>
    <option value="Пеноблочный" <?= $product['tip-doma']=='Пеноблочный' ? ' selected' : ''; ?>>Пеноблочный</option>
    <option value="Шлакоблочный" <?= $product['tip-doma']=='Шлакоблочный' ? ' selected' : ''; ?>>Шлакоблочный</option>
    <option value="Шлакобетонный" <?= $product['tip-doma']=='Шлакобетонный' ? ' selected' : ''; ?>>Шлакобетонный</option>
    <option value="Щитовой" <?= $product['tip-doma']=='Щитовой' ? ' selected' : ''; ?>>Щитовой</option>
                </select>
      </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Примечание:</td>
        <td><textarea  rows="5" cols="40" name="premich"><?= isset($_GET['red_id']) ? $product['premich'] : ''; ?></textarea></td>
      </tr>
      <tr style="display:none;">
        <td>Дата:</td>
        <td><input type="text" name="time" value="<?= $dt ?><?= $date ?>"></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td colspan="2"><input class="btn btn-success btn-sm" type="submit" value="Сохранить"></td>
      </tr>
    </table>
    </div>
    </div>
  </form>
<div class="resultat">
  <div class="box-header">
    <div class="title">Список всех клиентов и наличие их в базе сайта</div>
  </div>
  <div class="box-content">
  <table id="example" class="display" border='1'>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>#</th>
      <th>Имя</th>
      <th>Телефон</th>
      <th>Категория</th>
      <th>Район</th>
      <th>Бюджет</th>
      <th>Площадь</th>
      <th>Этаж</th>
      <th>Тип дома</th>
      <th>Примечание</th>
      <th>Дата</th>
      <th>Редактирование</th>
      <th>Удаление</th>
      </thead>
    </tr>
    <?php
      $sql = mysqli_query($link, 'SELECT * FROM `users`');
      while ($result = mysqli_fetch_array($sql)) {
        echo '<tr>' .
             "<td>{$result['id']}</td>" .
             "<td>{$result['name']}</td>" .
             "<td>{$result['phone']}</td>" .
             "<td>{$result['category']}</td>" .
             "<td>{$result['region']}</td>" .
             "<td>{$result['money']}</td>" .
             "<td>{$result['area']}</td>" .
             "<td>{$result['etaj']}</td>" .
             "<td>{$result['tip-doma']}</td>" .
             "<td>{$result['premich']}</td>" .
             "<td>{$result['time']}</td>" .
             "<td><a href='?red_id={$result['id']}'>Изменить</a></td>" .
       "<td><a href='?del_id={$result['id']}'>Удалить</a></td>" .
             '</tr>';
      }
    ?>
            <tfoot>
            <tr>
                <th></th>
                <th></th>
                <th></th>
                <th></th>
                <th></th>
                <th></th>
                <th></th>
                <th></th>
                <th></th>
                <th></th>
                <th></th>
            </tr>
        </tfoot>
  </table>
  </div><a class="btn btn-success btn-sm" href="?add=new">Добавить нового клиента</a>
  </div>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [PHP код выдает ошибку Notice: Undefined variable:](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/883240/php-%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%b4-%d0%b2%d1%8b%d0%b4%d0%b0%d0%b5%d1%82-%d0%be%d1%88%d0%b8%d0%b1%d0%ba%d1%83-notice-undefined-variable)

Answer (score 1):

вот эту часть, замените, со строки 78:

```
$date = date('d-m-Y');
if (isset($_GET['red_id'])) {
  $edit = 'Изменение клиента';
  $date = $product['time'];
}else {
  $add = 'Добавление клиента в базу';
}
```

а там где выводите просто $date:

```
<td><input type="text" name="time" value="<?= $date ?>"></td>
```

Comment: 15-01-202015-01-2020
Так тогда дата выводиться, т.е дублируется

Comment: не скопируйте, а вынесите за if

Comment: я так и сделал.

Comment: при добавлении клиента берется время текущее, а если редактируется клиент, то дата как в базе

Comment: поправил ответ, думаю это то что нужно

Answer (score 1):

212 строку удалить и вместо нее написать это:

```
<? if (isset($_GET['red_id'])) 
{
// ничего не делать
}
else 
{?>
  <td><input type="text" name="time" value="<?= $dt ?><?= $date ?>"></td>
<?}?>
```

Comment: 15-01-2020<br /><b>Notice</b>:  Undefined variable: date in <b>E:\OpenServer\OSPanel\domains\testtt10.ru\all_users(new).php</b> on line <b>218</b><br />

Comment: не пропустили ли вы знак $ перед date.    вот тут:
  <td><input type="text" name="time" value="<?= $dt ?><?= $date ?>"></td>

Comment: Не, я просто скопировал и вставил